# How to add function to be called onclick of button which is a part of template literal?

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I have a button as a part of template literal. I want to invoke a prototype function (with arguments) on click of the button. How do I do that?

I have found that by registering the function to be invoked, as a part of window, this can be achieved. But I want the function which is a part of prototype to be invoked. 
In below example, `showFilmDetails` needs to be invoked and the signature of it should be

```js
FilmCard.prototype.showFilmDetails = function(url){
    alert(url);
}
```

Sample code:

```js
    function FilmCard(data){

    }

    FilmCard.prototype.render = function(data){
        return this.getTemplate(data);
    }

    window.showFilmDetails = function(url){
        alert(url);
    }

    FilmCard.prototype.getTemplate = function(data){
        var self = this;
        return `
            <div class="card">
                <h4><button onclick="showFilmDetails('${data.url}')">${data.title}</button></h4>
                <div>
                    <div>Director: ${data.director}</div>
                    <div>Producer: ${data.producer}</div>
                    <div>Release Date: ${data.release_date}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    }
```

How can I invoke the function after making it a part of prototype and still alert the evaluated url?
I do not want to add event listener explicitly on the button.

Comment: What happens currently?  To me it seems like this should work.  Does it throw an error, what does it say?

Comment: Can you use event delegation here, you would not need to assign an onclick. Store the data in `data-url="${data.url}"`

Comment: "A button" is not part of a template literal. It seems like html markup for a button is part of the string. You should simply not do that, and instead install your event handlers using the DOM.

Comment: @ChrisBarr currently it works, but if I update the showFilmDetails to be a part of prototype, it throws errors

Comment: @Bibberty For now, I have  added url. The functionality can be very complex later. I need to pass the function.

Comment: @Bergi In that case, how can I pass the url as parameter?

Comment: @Ankita you'd pass parameters by using a closure as the event handler function

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by enclosing function in paranthesis.

```
FilmCard.prototype.showFilmDetails = (url) => {
    alert(url);
}

FilmCard.prototype.getTemplate = function(data){
    var self = this;
    return `
        <div class="card">
            <h4><button onclick="(${self.showFilmDetails})('${data.url}')">${data.title}</button></h4>
            <div>
                <div>Director: ${data.director}</div>
                <div>Producer: ${data.producer}</div>
                <div>Release Date: ${data.release_date}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
}
```